# Pathauto unable to bulk update contents alias with AJAX error

Tags: 7, path-aliases

In some way I have imported a legacy large database schema to Drupal's database schema. Everything works fine and the imported contents is working fine as nodes.

However, when I try to perform Bulk Update for aliases via `admin/config/search/path/update_bulk`, *using [pathauto](/questions/tagged/pathauto) module*, I got the following error message after about 4825 items :

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows. Path: /drupal/batch?render=overlay&id=1074&op=do StatusText: Service unavailable (with message) ResponseText: EntityMalformedException: Missing bundle property on entity of type node. in entity_extract_ids() (line 7844 of /xxxxx/drupal/includes/common.inc).
```

The following is a screen shot:

[image]

Clicking on the link titled **Please continue to the error Page** just send me to the bulk Update page with error message:

`An error occurred while processing pathauto_bulk_update_batch_process with arguments : pathauto_bulk_update_batch_process`

I could not able to find more detailed debug info and I don't know what's the matter?

Last version of Pathauto is used.

Answer (score 0):

I have just find the cause of the issue. It is just two records of `node` table among about 13K records has no `type` field value.

To solve it, using PHPMyAdmin I have filled them with the machine name of an available content type. in my case it is `archieve`